# mongodb query explain and index nscanned bigger than nscannedObjects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I been having a problem with my query. its not performing well.

its doing like 300ms - 1000ms.

I added index on each of the column. but can't seem to get it right.

sorry forgot to mention the document below is the query for upsert.

there is just an additiona {value.count:1}

document:

```
    {
            "_id.browser" : "Facebook",
            "_id.c1" : "hpb",
            "_id.c2" : "003",
            "_id.c3" : "us100_01",
            "_id.c4" : "us-18-13a",
            "_id.campaign_id" : "47cff2989aef12808a8a596b9b703efc",
            "_id.city" : "Edgewood",
            "_id.cloaked" : "0",
            "_id.country" : "United States",
            "_id.date_visited" : "2016-11-16",
            "_id.device_name" : "Samsung Galaxy S6",
            "_id.device_type" : "mobile",
            "_id.domain" : "healthypowerbuzz.com",
            "_id.hour_visited" : "10",
            "_id.isp" : "AT&T U-verse",
            "_id.landingpage_id" : "38a67be59dc9d8f6db81be94b207f2d7",
            "_id.netspeed_id" : NumberLong(3),
            "_id.offer_id" : [ 
                {
                    "offer_id" : "cd0d1a0fa7021b99a6f1b630cac64a39"
                }, 
                {
                    "offer_id" : "1f42d6d81d69bf8c9912ae75544eea9c"
                }
            ],
            "_id.org" : "AT&T U-verse",
            "_id.platform" : "Android",
            "_id.server_id" : "b5e04772f2ee237a36f24e8298c3d002",
            "_id.set" : "13",
            "_id.traffic_account_id" : "cdd60f26f1723f05ee4e964a8e6f43a7",
            "_id.week_visited" : "Wednesday",
"value.count" : 100
        }
```

query:

```
db.tes.update(
   {
        "_id.browser" : "Facebook",
        "_id.c1" : "hpb",
        "_id.c2" : "003",
        "_id.c3" : "us100_01",
        "_id.c4" : "us-18-13a",
        "_id.campaign_id" : "47cff2989aef12808a8a596b9b703efc",
        "_id.city" : "Edgewood",
        "_id.cloaked" : "0",
        "_id.country" : "United States",
        "_id.date_visited" : "2016-11-16",
        "_id.device_name" : "Samsung Galaxy S6",
        "_id.device_type" : "mobile",
        "_id.domain" : "healthypowerbuzz.com",
        "_id.hour_visited" : "10",
        "_id.isp" : "AT&T U-verse",
        "_id.landingpage_id" : "38a67be59dc9d8f6db81be94b207f2d7",
        "_id.netspeed_id" : NumberLong(3),
        "_id.offer_id" : [ 
            {
                "offer_id" : "cd0d1a0fa7021b99a6f1b630cac64a39"
            }, 
            {
                "offer_id" : "1f42d6d81d69bf8c9912ae75544eea9c"
            }
        ],
        "_id.org" : "AT&T U-verse",
        "_id.platform" : "Android",
        "_id.server_id" : "b5e04772f2ee237a36f24e8298c3d002",
        "_id.set" : "13",
        "_id.traffic_account_id" : "cdd60f26f1723f05ee4e964a8e6f43a7",
        "_id.week_visited" : "Wednesday"},
   {
     $inc: { value.count:1 }
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

I added a compound index on each of those. because I use it for upsert $inc count: 1. but its really slow.

when I explain I get this. I need help on how to handle this.

```
"n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 7773,
    "nscanned" : 15546,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 7773,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 15546,
```

Comment: What's your query statement?

Comment: Please note that index will make read faster but write slower, so if you are thinking that having lot of indexes will make insert or update faster, the idea is unfounded. It would help you to get to the record faster but when you update or insert, there is extra burden to manage indexing for that insert or update. Also share your query so that people can guess the bottleneck of the issue.

Comment: added my query.